# GAS: how to always read a cell data as a text in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In ma Google Application Script project I need to make sure that a cell data is always read as a text. To make sure that it happens like that I added `.setNumberFormat('@STRING@')` after each `.appendRow()`. To make 100% sure I even change the format after I update a cell.

But it happened that in the middle of spreadsheet there was row where the formatting was not text but .... I guess it had no formatting.

So when reading and working with such data an error was created `Thu Mar 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) Error   TypeError: data[row][1].split is not a function  at getTabulatorData(web functions:445:34)`

because split() function does not work on date object.

The data saved in the cell is `3/11/2021`

The current code how to get data is

```
var range = sheetData.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow, columns)
var data  = range.getValues()
```

If I use

```
var dataTMP = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, sheetName+"!"+range.getA1Notation(),
                                                         {valueRenderOption:"FORMATTED_VALUE"})
```

then I get correct text value even I format the cell as a date.

Is this correct way to read data as text? In Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) is written

```
// This code uses the Sheets Advanced Service, but for most use cases
// the built-in method SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
//     .getRange(range).getValues(values) is more appropriate.
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
```

Question 1: Does `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId,sheetName+"!"+range.getA1Notation(),{valueRenderOption:"FORMATTED_VALUE"})` give me always save data as a raw text?

Question 2: Is there a way for  `.getRange().getValues()` how to read, interpret save data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) instead of .getValues(). The first will return the values as strings.

Comment: Great, I did not  know this. Thanx